# Api to post a comment in instagram using instagram gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, social-networking, instagram

I have tried by using the following code,

```
client = Instagram.client(:access_token => "My_Access_Token")
result = client.create_media_comment("Media_Id", "Comment")
```

but i'm getting the following error,

```
POST https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/Media_Id/comments.json: 400: Please visit http://bit.ly/instacomments for commenting access
```

How can i resolve this?

Comment: You need to have special access granted to your Client ID. Go to the link in the error message and request access. Good luck though... they have not answered my requests for many months.

Comment: yeah, you need explicit commenting permission. I am also in the same situation. it's been over a month. I've tried it from different channels a few times, no answer from their side though.

Answer (score 0):

You should be passing an actual id for the piece of Instagram media on which you want to create a comment rather than the "Media_Id" string.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct (otherwise you won't get that error).

You need to go to http://bit.ly/instacomments and ask for commenting permission. Don't expect a reply anytime soon though, I've been waiting for a reply over a month, and seen people getting replies for that after three or four months.